# What does __FILE__ mean in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, self-reference

I see this all the time in Ruby:

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../../config/environment"
```

What does `__FILE__` mean?

Comment: To help tie together references, also see https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/143383 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325759/is-require-file-expand-path-file-the-best-practice?lq=1

Answer (score 157, accepted):

It is a reference to the current file name. In the file `foo.rb`, `__FILE__` would be interpreted as `"foo.rb"`.

**Edit:** Ruby 1.9.2 and 1.9.3 appear to behave a little differently from what Luke Bayes said in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224379/what-does-file-mean-in-ruby#comment1243516_224383). With these files:

```ruby
# test.rb
puts __FILE__
require './dir2/test.rb'
```

```ruby
# dir2/test.rb
puts __FILE__
```

Running `ruby test.rb` will output

```
test.rb
/full/path/to/dir2/test.rb
```

Comment: This answer is not accurate. __FILE__ is the "relative" path to the file from the current execution directory - not absolute. You must use File.expand_path(__FILE__) to get the absolute path

Comment: Double underscores were automatically removed within the comment above.

Comment: is this still true in ruby 1.9.2?

Comment: @Zasz It works kinda different in 1.9.2.  The file initially loaded has a relative \_\_FILE\_\_, but other included/required files have absolute paths.

Comment: @LukeBayes You can preserve underscores and other special characters in Stack Overflow comments by surrounding the literal text with backticks. Write `\`__FILE__\`` to get `__FILE__`.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane Before someone misreads this and tries to enter this into a ruby script, do not write `\`__FILE__\`` in ruby, unless you want the world to maybe explode.

Comment: I've found [references](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/doc/keywords_rdoc.html) to the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-__FILE__), but they're not too specific.

Comment: `__FILE__` is relative only for the first (main) file. Because in this case `load_file()` is called [directly](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v3_1_3/ruby.c#L2127) and passed `$0`. When requiring files `require_internal()` [uses `search_required()`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v3_1_3/load.c#L1117-L1120) to find the file and passes to `load_file()` the [resulting absolute path](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v3_1_3/load.c#L1136). The behavior is handy to make `$0 == __FILE__` kind of checks (self-executing files).

Answer (score 64):

The value of `__FILE__` is a relative path that is created and stored (but never updated) when your file is loaded. This means that if you have any calls to `Dir.chdir` anywhere else in your application, this path will expand incorrectly.

```
puts __FILE__
Dir.chdir '../../'
puts __FILE__
```

One workaround to this problem is to store the expanded value of `__FILE__` outside of any application code. As long as your `require` statements are at the top of your definitions (or at least before any calls to `Dir.chdir`), this value will continue to be useful after changing directories.

```
$MY_FILE_PATH = File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))

# open class and do some stuff that changes directory

puts $MY_FILE_PATH
```

Comment: ```This means that if you have any calls to Dir.chdir anywhere else in your application, this path will expand incorrectly.``` The path expanded correctly under my test. My ruby version is 2.3.7, maybe the newer ruby version fixed this issue.

Answer (score 29):

`__FILE__` is the filename with extension of the file containing the code being executed.

In `foo.rb`, `__FILE__` would be "foo.rb".

If `foo.rb` were in the dir `/home/josh` then `File.dirname(__FILE__)` would return `/home/josh`.

Comment: Exactly looking for this. +1 :=) @Ethan

Comment: A link to the documentation [here](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-__FILE__)

Answer (score 18):

In Ruby, the Windows version anyways, I just checked and `__FILE__` does not contain the full path to the file. Instead it contains the path to the file relative to where it's being executed from.

In PHP `__FILE__` is the full path (which in my opinion is preferable). This is why, in order to make your paths portable in Ruby, you really need to use this:

```
File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "relative/path/to/file")
```

I should note that in Ruby 1.9.1 `__FILE__` contains the full path to the file, the above description was for when I used Ruby 1.8.7.

In order to be compatible with both Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.1 (not sure about 1.9) you should require files by using the construct I showed above.

Comment: You need to prepend a slash to your relative path: `File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/relative/path/to/file")`

Comment: You should never hard-code the directory separator. Use File.join instead:

`File.expand_path( File.join( File.dirname(__FILE__), "relative", "path", "to", "file") )`

Comment: Andrew, can you helpe-me please? I am writing to a file using the following:                      path = YAML::load_file(File.open(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/massa/users.yml")))       path[:cad_user][:user] = input_email_create.value                                                                          File.open(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/massa/users.yml'), 'w') {|f| f.write path.to_yaml } but I get the message: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen

Comment: Not sure how it behaved back then, but these days `__FILE__ == $0` for the first (main) file, and an absolute path for the rest. This is handy for `__FILE__ == $0` kind of checks (self-executing files). More about it in my [other comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224379/what-does-file-mean-in-ruby#comment132157943_224383).