# Is require File.expand_path(..., __FILE__) the best practice?

Tags: ruby, require

Is `require File.expand_path(..., __FILE__)` the best way to require other files within a project?

Comment: I'd +100 this if I could. It's something I wish I could do without.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224379/what-does-file-mean-in-ruby

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby: require vs require\_relative - best practice to workaround running in both Ruby <1.9.2 and >=1.9.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333286/ruby-require-vs-require-relative-best-practice-to-workaround-running-in-both)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In Ruby 1.9.2 + `require_relative` is probably the more correct way to do it.

`require` was changed to not include your `'.'` directory for security reasons. `require_relative` was added to provide a local-file solution for modules relative to your *calling script's* path.

You can [search here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=require_relative), particularly in "[What is require_relative in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672586/what-is-require-relative-in-ruby)", and the internets and find usage tricks and the [why-for messages](https://web.archive.org/web/20110817002255/http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/148978) explaining how it came about.

Comment: Also, "[Ruby: require vs require_relative - best practice to workaround running in both Ruby <1.9.2 and >=1.9.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333286/ruby-require-vs-require-relative-best-practice-to-workaround-running-in-both)" is a great thread explaining this.

Answer (score 7):

In Ruby 2.x you can use [`Kernel#__dir__`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Kernel.html#method-i-__dir__)

Answer (score 3):

Unless you modify `$LOAD_PATH`, which would be a good idea if you keep loading from the same directory structure, you are stuck doing it that way.

The way I've taken to doing it, to ensure things are as cross-platform as possible, is this:

```
require File.expand_path(File.join(*%w[ ... ]), File.dirname(__FILE__))
```

It's a little verbose, but it results in the shortest possible path and the least amount of syntax fluff in most cases.

A more specific example would be:

```
require File.expand_path(File.join(*%w[ .. lib example ]), File.dirname(__FILE__))
```

You can combine this with a modification to `$LOAD_PATH` to simplify things if you're loading a lot of files and do this:

```
$LOAD_PATH << File.expand_path(File.join(*%w[ .. lib ]), File.dirname(__FILE__))

require 'example'
```

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby 1.8.x, where you don't have `require_relative` in core, `File.expand_path(...,__FILE__)` won't work.

Suppose `__FILE__ == "/home/yourname/foo.rb"`. `File.expand_path("bar.rb",__FILE__)` gives `"/home/yourname/foo.rb/bar.rb`.

What you want is `File.expand_path("bar.rb",File.dirname(__FILE__))` which returns `"/home/yourname/bar.rb"`

You could also get `require_relative` from the [backports gem](http://github.com/marcandre/backports).

Comment: you can always do `require File.expand_path("../baz.rb", __FILE__)` to include baz.rb from foo.rb in the same directory.

Comment: Following on from Matt's comment, I see that `File.expand_path("../../lib/mygem.rb", __FILE__)` is an actual example given in the 2.1.0 docs for `expand_path`.  But that involves pretending a non-directory is a directory and then moving to its supposed parent!  I'm baffled that the official docs would recommend such a deviant approach, and I wonder if it only works through some brittle side-effect of the implementation which could change behaviour in future versions.  I think the `dirname` approach is much cleaner.