# File.expand_path("../../Gemfile", __FILE__) How does this work? Where is the file?

Tags: ruby

`ENV["BUNDLE_GEMFILE"] = File.expand_path("../../Gemfile", __FILE__)`

I'm just trying to access a .rb file from the some directory and a tutorial is telling me to use this code but I don't see how it is finding the gem file.

Comment: Also see question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333286

Answer (score 202, accepted):

```
File.expand_path('../../Gemfile', __FILE__)
```

is a somewhat ugly Ruby idiom for getting the absolute path to a file when you know the path relative to the current file. Another way of writing it is this:

```
File.expand_path('../Gemfile', File.dirname(__FILE__))
```

both are ugly, but the first variant is shorter. The first variant is, however, also very non-intuitive until you get the hang of it. Why the extra `..`? (but the second variant may give a clue as to why it is needed).

This is how it works: `File.expand_path` returns the absolute path of the first argument, relative to the second argument (which defaults to the current working directory). `__FILE__` is the path to the file the code is in. Since the second argument in this case is a path to a file, and `File.expand_path` assumes a directory, we have to stick an extra `..` in the path to get the path right. This is how it works:

`File.expand_path` is basically implemented like this (in the following code `path` will have the value of `../../Gemfile` and `relative_to` will have the value of `/path/to/file.rb`):

```
def File.expand_path(path, relative_to=Dir.getwd)
  # first the two arguments are concatenated, with the second argument first
  absolute_path = File.join(relative_to, path)
  while absolute_path.include?('..')
    # remove the first occurrence of /<something>/..
    absolute_path = absolute_path.sub(%r{/[^/]+/\.\.}, '')
  end
  absolute_path
end
```

(there's a little bit more to it, it expands `~` to the home directory and so on -- there are probably also some other issues with the code above)

Stepping through a call to the code above `absolute_path` will first get the value `/path/to/file.rb/../../Gemfile`, then for each round in the loop the first `..` will be removed, along with the path component before it. First `/file.rb/..` is removed, then on the next round `/to/..` is removed, and we get `/path/Gemfile`.

To make a long story short, `File.expand_path('../../Gemfile', __FILE__)` is a trick to get the absolute path of a file when you know the path relative to the current file. The extra `..` in the relative path is to eliminate the name of the file in `__FILE__`.

In Ruby 2.0 there is a `Kernel` function called `__dir__` that is implemented as `File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))`.

Comment: Is there any reason why you shouldn't just use 'require_relative' other than incompatibility with pre Ruby 1.9.2?

Comment: As of Ruby 2.0 you can use `File.expand_path('../Gemfile',__dir__)`

Comment: This line from Theo finally got it to click for me `File.expand_path assumes a directory`, even though `__FILE__` is not a directory. For things to make sense use `__dir__` which actually is a directory.

Answer (score 9):

Two references:

1. [File::expand_path method documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/File.html#M002540)
2. [How does `__FILE__` work in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224379/what-does-file-mean-in-ruby)

I stumbled across this today:

[boot.rb commit in the Rails Github](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/f7e33620caffecb7f065c5e4f5a19597f8c35cdd)

If you go up two directories from boot.rb in the directory tree:

[/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/07567aea5f0c6f14a53f511ab4cc46201b669795/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates)

you see Gemfile, which leads me to believe that `File.expand_path("../../Gemfile", __FILE__)` references following file: `/path/to/this/file/../../Gemfile`

Comment: Thanks for the post, but this came from the gembundler tutorial so I was trying to understand it exactly how they had it :)