# why File.expand_path(__FILE__)?

Tags: ruby

I've been studying ruby and frameworks like Sinatra and Rails, and I see this kind of code:

```
File.expand_path(..., __FILE__) # this returns something like /Users/.../app/something.rb
```

Instead of just starting from:

```
File.expand_path(..., ".") # this returns something like /Users/.../app
```

Since both return valid and known paths, is there any reason to start navigating from `\__FILE__` instead of "."?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does \_\_FILE\_\_ mean in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224379/what-does-file-mean-in-ruby)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__dir__` or (`__FILE__`) is not necessarily the same as `"."`. The former is the location of the file. The latter is the location from where the main command was called (or wherever it was changed to by commands like `Dir.chdir`).

Comment: `__dir__` is affected by pwd too. Can't prove it right now though. But pretty sure I faced issues about it.

Answer (score 0):

`__FILE__` represents the *current file*, whereas `'.'` represents the *current directory* of code execution. So, you have to go a level (`..`) before the current file to reach to a particular file as compared to `'.'`.

From what I [have read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4479926/1376448), it **is** sort of ugly way of using it. Developers use it as per intuition and it's entirely upto to conventions adopted by project/community.

Comment: Your link is outdated. The point is that `__FILE__` requires extra `..`, which makes it tricky. But in modern Ruby, `__dir__` should be used to avoid that problem.

Comment: Hm. Agreed. Didn't know about the `__dir__` idiom. Maybe, `__FILE__` is still being used in some projects to support back compatibility to previous Ruby versions.