# How does File.expand_path work?

Tags: ruby

I'm not sure I understand the order in which operations are done with `File.expand_path`. Below is an example `pry` session:

```
[1] pry(main)> File.expand_path('.')
=> "/Users/max/Dropbox/work/src/github.com/mbigras/foobie"
[2] pry(main)> File.expand_path('..')
=> "/Users/max/Dropbox/work/src/github.com/mbigras"
[3] pry(main)> File.expand_path('..', "cats")
=> "/Users/max/Dropbox/work/src/github.com/mbigras/foobie"
[4] pry(main)> File.expand_path('..', __FILE__)
=> "/Users/max/Dropbox/work/src/github.com/mbigras/foobie"
[5] pry(main)> File.expand_path('../lib', __FILE__)
=> "/Users/max/Dropbox/work/src/github.com/mbigras/foobie/lib"
[7] pry(main)> File.expand_path('./lib')
=> "/Users/max/Dropbox/work/src/github.com/mbigras/foobie/lib"
[8] pry(main)> File.expand_path('./lib', __FILE__)
=> "/Users/max/Dropbox/work/src/github.com/mbigras/foobie/(pry)/lib"
[9] pry(main)>
```

`[1]` makes sense, I'm expanding the path of the current working directory.

`[2]` makes sense, I'm expanding the path of the parent directory of the cwd

`[3]` doesn't make sense, I accept from reading [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4479926/2909897) that for some reason ruby implicitly takes the `File.dirname` of the second arg and in the case of `File.dirname('cats')` it expands to the cwd `.` because `'cats'` isn't nested. But then why doesn't `File.expand_path('..', '.')` have the same result?

```
[18] pry(main)> File.expand_path('..', 'cats')
=> "/Users/max/Dropbox/work/src/github.com/mbigras/foobie"
[19] pry(main)> File.dirname('cats')
=> "."
[20] pry(main)> File.expand_path('..', '.')
=> "/Users/max/Dropbox/work/src/github.com/mbigras"
```

`[4]` doesn't make sense but for the same reason as `[3]`. In this case the "random string" is `"(pry)"` because `p __FILE__ #=> "(pry)"` while inside a pry session.

`[5]` doesn't make sense, why would `File.expand_path` go to seemingly noone's parent directory and then magically come back to the cwd and decide to go into `lib`

`[7]` makes sense, but doesn't help me understand `[5]`

`[8]` doesn't make sense, why is the "random string" now wedged between the cwd `.` and `lib`

From the docs:

```
File.expand_path("../../lib/mygem.rb", __FILE__)
#=> ".../path/to/project/lib/mygem.rb"
```

> So first it resolves the parent of __FILE__, that is bin/, then go to the parent, the root of the project and appends lib/mygem.rb.

The order of operations doesn't really add up to me.

1. Take `File.dirname(__FILE__)`
2. Go to the parent which is the root
3. append lib/mygem.rb

Steps 2 and 3 don't help. Why are we going to the parent? Why did we even do Step 1 in the first place? Why is there `../..`? Doesn't that mean go two levels up from the current working directory?

Would love some guiding principles to understand these examples.

Edit to add the Gold:

> `File.expand_path` goes to the first parameter from the directory specified by the second parameter (`Dir.pwd` if not present). - Eric Duminil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Theory

I think you missed a `..` while reading the answer you link to.

No `File.dirname` is ever done implicitely by `expand_path`.

```
File.expand_path('../../Gemfile', __FILE__)
#                 ^^ Note the difference between here and
#                 vv there
File.expand_path('../Gemfile', File.dirname(__FILE__))
```

What confused me at first was that the second parameter is always considered to be a directory by `File.expand_path`, even if it doesn't exist, even if it looks like a file or even if it is an existing file.

`File.expand_path` goes to the first parameter from the directory specified by the second parameter (`Dir.pwd` if not present).

## Examples

#### [3]

```
File.expand_path('..', "cats")
```

It is executed in the current directory, which is `"/Users/max/Dropbox/work/src/github.com/mbigras/foobie"`.

Is `cats` an existing file, an existing directory or a non-existent directory?

It doesn't matter to `File.expand_path` : `"cats"` is considered to be an existing directory, and `File.expand_path` starts inside it.

This command is equivalent to launching :

```
File.expand_path('..')
```

inside the `"/Users/max/Dropbox/work/src/github.com/mbigras/foobie/cats"` directory.

So `expand_path` goes back one directory, and lands back to :

```
"/Users/max/Dropbox/work/src/github.com/mbigras/foobie"
```

#### [4]

Same thing. It is equivalent to `File.expand_path('..')` from the (probably) non-existing :

`"/Users/max/Dropbox/work/src/github.com/mbigras/foobie/(pry)"`

So it is :

```
"/Users/max/Dropbox/work/src/github.com/mbigras/foobie"
```

#### [5]

Going from [4], it just goes to the subfolder `lib`.

#### [8]

Starting from `"/Users/max/Dropbox/work/src/github.com/mbigras/foobie/(pry)"`
, it just goes to the subfolder `lib`.

Once again, `File.expand_path` never checks if the corresponding folders and subfolders exist.