# Why does this dotCover rake task fail using these relative file paths?

Tags: rake, teamcity, teamcity-7.0, dotcover, albacore

I'm having some issues getting dotCover to work in an Albacore `exec` task using relative paths.

```
@xUnitRunnerPath = Pathname.new('../../Tools/xUnit/xunitcontrib-dotcover.2.0/xunit.runner.utility.dll').realpath
@myTestDll = 'C:\PathToProj\My.Project.Tests\bin\Release\My.project.Tests.dll'
@outputDir = 'C:\PathToTestResults\'

exec :testCoverage do |cmd|
    cmd.command = "C:/BuildAgent/tools/dotCover/dotCover.exe"
    cmd.parameters = [
        "cover",
        "/targetexecutable=$$#{@xUnitRunnerPath}$$",
        "/targetarguments=$$#{@myTestDll}$$",
        "/output=#{@outputDir}/My.Project.Tests.dll.dcvr"
    ]
end
```

The `dotCover` error is unhelpful just telling me paths are wrong

```
Failed to convert relative paths to absolute in parameters for the 'cover' 
command. The given path's format is not supported.
```

This doesn't provide much help and I've also tried dotcover help cover for the help on that but doesn't give many clues as to what's going wrong.

I've followed [this post about rake and dotcover](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/297902) and also [this question](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/439535).  Maybe I'm missing the relevant documentation here but it would be really helpful to be able to get this working.

---

EDIT: I just found this relating to [relative and absolute paths](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DCVR-3800), perhaps because I'm using absolute paths I need the following.  We'll find out tomorrow

```
/AnalyseTargetArguments=false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that's interested here's my final rake tasks working

```
task :unitTestsWithCoverageReport => [ :unitTestsWithCoverage, :coverageServiceMessage ]

exec :unitTestsWithCoverage do |cmd|
    fullPathAssemblies = []

    @unitTestAssemblies.each do |testAssembly|
        testAssemblyRealPath = Pathname.new(testAssembly).realpath
        fullPathAssemblies << testAssemblyRealPath
    end

    cmd.command = @dotCoverRealPath
    cmd.parameters = [
        "cover",
        "/AnalyseTargetArguments=False",
        "/TargetExecutable=#{@xUnitRunnerRealPath}",
        "/TargetArguments=\"#{fullPathAssemblies.join ';'}\"",
        "/Output=#{@testResultsRealPath}/coverage.dcvr"
        ]
end

task :coverageServiceMessage do |t|
    puts "##teamcity[importData type='dotNetCoverage' tool='dotcover' path='#{@testResultsRealPath}/coverage.dcvr']"
end
```

Many thanks to @AnthonyMastrean as he showed me some really nice little ruby tricks and how I should be structuring my rake file properly.

Comment: Can you provide some commentary on why/how this works vs. the previous rakefile?

Comment: It appears that the dotCover command line accepts _multiple_ target arguments. Do you need a coverage report file per assembly? If not, you could push all the assembly paths into that target argument instead of creating a task per assembly.

Comment: I'll give that a go, thanks.  Also I don't like that you've named your task `import_data` when what you're actually doing is creating a `service message` for teamcity to interpret.  That may involve teamcity importing data but that's not what the task does.

Comment: `import_data` is just a method that I defined to wrap up printing the service message. I prototyped a small [TeamCity service message gem](https://github.com/anthonymastrean/teamcity_service_messages#readme). And my buddy, Henrik Feldt, is reworking the internals of Albacore with [the same features](https://github.com/Albacore/albacore/blob/clean_slate/lib/albacore/ext/teamcity.rb).

Comment: Liking the look of the TC integration into albacore, nice looking gem too

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to remix the rakefile/tasks from your own answer. There are some Ruby/Rake conventions that you should follow to appeal to a broader audience. And I have some opinions on how to write awesome rakefiles. In particular...

#### 1. Don't invoke/execute Rake tasks directly

```
Rake::Task[:unitTestWithCoverage].execute( testAssembly )
```

There's all sorts of reasons why you don't want to mess with direct Rake `invoke` or `execute`. One of them doesn't invoke dependent tasks, one only runs dependent tasks once... it gets goofy. There should always be a way to construct properly defined and dependent tasks.

#### 2. Don't parameterize "internal" tasks

```
exec :unitTestWithCoverage, [:testAssembly] do |cmd, testAssembly|
```

You probably have a static list or wildcard-matching list of test assemblies. You should be able to construct concrete tasks without using parameters. I only use parameterized tasks when the user can invoke them with custom input from the command line.

#### 3. No need to create paths inside each task

```
testAssemblyRealPath = Pathname.new(testAssembly).realpath
testAssemblyName = File.basename(testAssemblyRealPath)
```

We're gonna explore the Rake [`FileList`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html) to figure out how to create custom, lazy, [mapped](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html) lists of filenames/paths/arbitrary-strings!

## The Remix (updated)

*I made a critical mistake in my first answer (which I maintain at the bottom, for reference). I'll explain what went wrong in that section for your/my education!*

What follows is my new recommendation. This should have been obvious to me because I made the same mistake with an mspec test runner task in my own builds.

```
dotcover_path = 'path/to/dotcover.exe'
xunit_runner_path = 'path/to/xunitrunner.exe'

test_assemblies = FileList['path/to/output/**/*.test.dll']
coverage_results = "#{test_results_path}/coverage_results.dcvr"

task :cover_all => [ :tests_with_coverage, :publish_coverage_results ]

exec :tests_with_coverage do |cmd|
  cmd.comand = dotcover_path
  cmd.parameters = [ 
    "cover",
    "/AnalyseTargetArguments=False",
    "/TargetExecutable=\"#{xunit_runner_path}\"",
    "/TargetArguments=\"#{test_assemblies.join ','}\"",
    "/Output=\"#{coverage_results}\""
  ]
end

task :publish_coverage_results => [ :tests_with_coverage ] do 
  import_data 'dotNetCoverage', 'dotCover', coverage_results
end

def import_data(type, tool, file)
  puts "##teamcity[importData type='#{type}' tool='#{tool}' path='#{file}']"
end
```

### The Explanation

I default to absolute paths (usually by using [`File.expand_path`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html) and the [`__FILE__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224379/what-does-file-mean-in-ruby) constant). There are tools/tasks that require relative paths, but you can always play with methods like `File.basename`.

```
dotcover_path = 'path/to/dotcover.exe'
xunit_runner_path = 'path/to/xunitrunner.exe'
```

We can still use a [`FileList`](http://rake.rubyforge.org/classes/Rake/FileList.html) of built assemblies to define the target assemblies. We won't evaluate it until the body of the test task executes.

```
test_assemblies = FileList['path/to/output/**/*.test.dll']
```

The coverage runner supports multiple assemblies with a single results file. This way we don't have another complicated `pathmap`.

```
coverage_results = "#{test_results_path}/coverage_results.dcvr"
```

Call this from your CI server to run the tests and the coverage results published.

```
task :cover_all => [ :tests_with_coverage, :publish_coverage_results ]
```

This task is now plain and simple. Some notes:
1. Use [`join`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-join) to turn the list of targets into a string of the correct format.
2. I tend to quote exec task parameters that have file paths (which requires escaping, `\"`).

```
exec :tests_with_coverage do |cmd|
  cmd.command = dotcover_path
  cmd.parameters = [ 
    "cover",
    "/AnalyseTargetArguments=False",
    "/TargetExecutable=\"#{xunit_runner_path}\"",
    "/TargetArguments=\"#{test_assemblies.join ','}\"",
    "/Output=\"#{coverage_results}\""
  ]
end
```

Same old publish task/method.

```
task publish_coverage_results => [ :tests_with_coverage ] do 
  import_data 'dotNetCoverage', 'dotCover', coverage_results
end

def import_data(type, tool, file)
  puts "##teamcity[importData type='#{type}' tool='#{tool}' path='#{file}']"
end
```

## The Old Remix

*Snipped to show the problem area, assume the rest was uninteresting or exists in the new solution, too.*

The test assemblies won't exist until *after* the build task. That's normally not a problem, since `FileList` is lazy. It won't evaluate until you enumerate over it (for example, by using `each`, `map`, or `zip`).

However, we immediately `each` over it to generate the test tasks... so this won't work. It'll have nothing in the list and generate no tasks. Or, even worse, it'll pickup the previous build's output and possibly do bad things (if you didn't completely clean the output directory).

```
test_assemblies = FileList['path/to/output/**/*.test.dll']
coverage_results = test_assemblies.pathmap "#{test_results_path}/%n.dcvr"
cover_task_names = test_assemblies.pathmap "cover_%n"

test_assemblies.zip(coverage_results, cover_task_names) do |assembly, results, task_name|
  exec task_name do |cmd|
    cmd.command = dotcover_path
    cmd.parameters = [ 
      "cover",
      "/AnalyseTargetArguments=False",
      "/TargetExecutable=#{xunit_path}",
      "/TargetArguments=#{assembly}",
      "/Output=#{results}"
    ]
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, much appreciated that you've taken the time to provide some deeper insight into the mistakes I made in my script.  However I find your code much more difficult to follow than mine but maybe it's because I'm new to ruby / rake.  Some links to the documentation on the clever bits like .zip and .pathmap would help because it looks a bit too much like magic for me.

Comment: I made a really bad mistake in my first answer, I tuned it up and it ended up much simpler. I would read something like [Eloquent Ruby](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0321584104) as an intro to Ruby language idioms. It helped me a lot!

Comment: I like the new way much more, thanks for the tip on the book as well, I'll definitely pick it up