# What exactly does $:.unshift(File.expand_path("../../lib", __FILE__)) do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rake-task, rakefile

There are a lot of threads on here about this already I know but none of the titles have this worded exactly like I did. I hope that we can clear this up a bit.

```
$:.unshift(File.expand_path("../../lib", __FILE__))
```

You see something like this in a lot of Ruby code.
Opinions vary whether this is proper or not.

Can we get a little explaination for each of its parts? There realy is a lot going on here. I only understand some of it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[**`$:`**](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Variables_and_Constants) holds *Load path for scripts and binary modules by load or require.* . And [**`Array#unshift`**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-unshift) will prepend the new path to `$:`. [**`File#expand_path`**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/File.html#method-c-expand_path) *Converts a pathname to an absolute pathname.* **`__FILE__`** is already answered here [**`What does __FILE__ mean in Ruby?`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224379/what-does-file-mean-in-ruby).

Comment: Thanks for that explaination @Arup.